# How to navigate to another page from the builder of the Main Page in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have a MainPage, which is the first one opened, when the Windows Phone Application is launched. If the settings is empty, I want to navigate to Settings Page. By the way it seems I can't do it in the builder. This is the C# code:

```
  public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

        checkSettings();
}

     private void checkSettings()
    {
        var applicationData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current;
        var roamingSettings = applicationData.RoamingSettings;
        string surname = (string)roamingSettings.Values["surname"];
        if (surname == null)
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(Settings));

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

And this what I got when I executed the application:

System.NullReferenceException 
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What do you think is the problem ? Is there any other solution can I do, to navigate to the other page ? Thank you

UPDATE with the full code WORKS !

I finally found the solution, with the load page handler. Now everything works !

```
private void check_action(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        checkSettings();
    }
```

Comment: What is Settings.isEmpty() method? It is a static method? Can you post it?

Comment: Seems that there are more problems in your code (`Message = null;`), which you haven't posted. Also you can't navigate in constructor also it's not a good idea. Maybe you can redirect navigation in app.xaml.cs file. You can try also to navigate in Loaded event.

Comment: I have updated the code, with also the method. What can be a possible solution ?